# Delphi ActiveX PDF export pages to jpg

Tags: delphi, pdf, activex, jpeg

I've installed the Acrobat ActiveX into Delphi.  I have no problem loading documents.  What I need to do is to cycle through each page of the document and export it to a jpg from inside Delphi.

Manually, I can click on a page to select it, right click and export that page to a jpg. Does anyone know if there's a way to automatically do this from within Delphi.

I've looked through here: [PDF Reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf) and don't see anything.  Or nothing that makes sense to me anyway.

I know there's several VCL components out there that will do it but spending several hundred dollars on a test project isn't in the cards.

Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking about the Acrobat reader? If so, where is the option to convert the page to jpeg? I can't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: Yes. Actually, it seems it was because the pages on one of the PDF's I looked at were imported as jpeg.  I was selecting an image stored in the PDF and exporting that. I'm guessing now that the only way to do it would be to grab the entire canvas.

Comment: You can use the SendInput function to mimic mouse clicks and keystrokes and copy images to the clipboard. That would be one quick and dirty way to automate your task.